# Series that converges to $1$ slowly

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to $1$, but it does so at a much faster rate than I'd like: $1/2,3/4,7/8...$.  In other words, after only a few terms we are really close to $1$ (for my taste).

Can you give an example of a series that congerges to $1$ very slowly, so that the partial sums approach $1$ is a more linear fashion?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}4}{\pi (2n+1)}$?

Comment: (Leibniz's formula for $\pi/4$ is well known to converge extremely slowly, so I multiplied by $4/\pi$ to make a slowly converging series to $1$.)

Comment: It's easy to modify a series to make it converge as slowly as you wish, so your question is not clear. What do you mean by "linear"?

Comment: Also "telescoping series" can be used to construct a limit that is approached as slowly as one wishes.  The Wikipedia article [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) will introduce the idea if you are unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take any sequence $s_n$ such that $s_n \to 1$ as slowly as you want, with $s_0 = 0$.  Let  $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$. Then the partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = s_n$.

Comment: This is the answer. Any calculus student can use this to construct a series!

Answer (score 2):

You can do $\frac 6{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)}$

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$?

Comment: @Vincent:  Yes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ converges for any $\alpha > 1$ to (let us note it) $l_{\alpha}$. Take $\frac{1}{l_{\alpha}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$.

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}$ also converges (even slowlier than the example above).

You won't have any nice analytical expression for the limit if you go that way, though.